# Export fusioncharts to pdfMake

Tags: fusioncharts, export-to-pdf, pdfmake

I am building a report with pdfMake in which I need to include some charts rendered at the web page with fusioncharts. The available client-side export options provided by fusioncharts aren't working for me because I need to obtain the image file (or base64) somehow to pass it to the function building the document, without having to retrieve it elsewhere.

I understand that fusioncharts have server-side export options, but I haven't found guidence or clear info about if this is kind of the start to the solution I am looking for.

AMcharts has the 'export to base64' feature just the way I need (link below); so any help, tips, solution or workaround to get it done with fusioncharts would be really appreciated.

https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/get-base64-representation-chart-image/

Answer (score 0):

You can get Base64 string data for FusionChart chart by consuming its API method `getSVGString`, using this method you will get SVG string for the chart which you can convert to Base64 string using JS via `window.btoa()`.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sikrigagan/2ovov3nL/

To know more about this method, check [this developer documentation page](http://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/api/fusioncharts/fusioncharts-methods.html#getSVGString).

Comment: This was really helpfull, but now I have the base64 string I'm getting an error when trying to insert it to the PDF layout saying that it isn't a valid image. Testing the base64 string (in this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/casiano/xadvz/), it actually displays a broken image icon, what could be the problem? I'm getting the base64 just as your example and then passing it to the PDF like this `var grafica64 = "data:image/jpeg;base64,"+grafica;` in which 'grafica' contains the base64 string.

Comment: Actually, when testing with the base64 string given in your fiddle example the result is the same, not working.

Comment: Which would be the correct mediatype for the syntax? `data:[<mediatype>][;base64],<data>`

Comment: `"data:image/svg+xml;base64,"+grafica` also not working

Comment: Media type syntax is `data:image/svg+xml;base64`. Are you facing the issue for a particular browser or across all the browsers?